# react-geolocated does not return the exact location

Tags: reactjs, geolocation

I'm using **react-geolocated 2.3.0** in my react app, but it does not return the exact location of the user, even with high accuracy enabled.

Comment: ... what's your code? MCVE please.

Comment: Here is my App.js file: 

[App.js](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/Am5660WP)